# Date Time format without time

Tags: php, date, time

I have a variable holding time in the format Apr 25, 2017 12:00:00 AM  I wish to convert it **to** 2017-04-25 .My result should be without time

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I did try with this date("H:i:s",strtotime($value['start'])) but its giving me time

Comment: this one too new Zend_Date(strtotime($value['rstart']));

Comment: I have added the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your string formatted date, to timestamp with `strtotime()` function. Then you can parameter `date()` function with converted timestamp, and format it with first parameter.

More about formatting: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('Apr 25, 2017 12:00:00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) method of PHP

```
$date = 'May 25, 2017 12:00:00 AM';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class:

```
$datestr = 'Apr 25, 2017 12:00:00 AM';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y h:i:s A', $datestr);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

**output**

```
2017-04-25
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date()` function:

```
$old_date="Apr 25, 2017 12:00:00 AM";
$new_date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($old_date));
echo $new_date;
```